# Pipe content of a div directly to a post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project where I need to have a formatted text box to enter large amounts of text. For this reason I am using a div with `contenteditable` on. I have been using a hidden input with the text copied into it. This seems very inefficient. Because I am going to be working with upwards of a thousand words and I don't want any browser lag, I was wondering if there is a way to pipe the content of the div directly to the post request.

If it helps, I'm using jquery in the application as well.

Comment: What do you mean by a "hidden attribute"? Attributes aren't visible to users, so what does it mean to hide them. Did you mean a hidden input?

Comment: You can't use a `textarea`?

Comment: A thousand words is not very much. `hiddeninput.value = div.textContent;` should not produce any noticeable lag.

Comment: I want to be able to format the text

Comment: Are you aware of `<textarea>`? I ask because of your reasoning: _I need to have a formatted text box to enter large amounts of text_

Comment: You can use an ajax request to submit the contents. This way you don't have to copy lots of data from one HTML element to another. If the request is successful, you can simply redirect the user. Otherwise show an error message.

Comment: From my understanding, it's impossible to have, say strikethrough letters or bold letters in a textarea

Comment: You can send the content of a contenteditable div directly (without any hidden input in the middle) via Ajax. Show us your actual code. It would help us a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the content of a contenteditable div directly (without any hidden input in the middle).

You just have to work on the string a little... If you want to take the line returns in account.

Example:

```js
$("#send").on("click",function(){
 var text = $("#typehere").html();
 
 // Remove the <br> and </div> tags
 // and replace the <div> by the new line chars
 
 // Text before
 console.log(text);
 text = text.replace(/(<\/div>)|(<br>)/g,"").replace(/<div>/g,"\r\n");
 
 // Text after (will be sent)
 console.log(text);
 
 
 // An ajax quick example - Commented since it obviously can't work.
 /*
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://a-domain[dot]com?something-to-handle-it.php",
  type:"post",
  data:{
    text: text
  },
  success:function(response){
    console.log("Ajax succeded");
  }
 });
 */
});
```

```css
#typehere{
  border:1px solid orange;
  height:12em;
  width:100%;
  margin:1em 0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="typehere" contenteditable></div>
<button id="send">Send</button>
```